# Angular 2+ how to reference component in a peer MODULE

Tags: angular, angular-components, angular-module, cross-reference

Angular 2 - 7: (Source below): I have SectionA Module with components a and b.  A peer of SectionA is SectionB module with components ba and bb.
The parent of BOTH SectionA and SectionB is called all-sections.module.ts.
In app.module, I ONLY reference 'all-sections module' and have no trouble showing each of the Section A and Section B components working (shown below).
Component 'a' CAN use 'b' in it's html, but I am unable to reference it's cousin 'bb' from SectionB.  Question: how to show 'bb' from 'a'.

[image]

SectionA module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { AComponent} from './a/a.component';
import { BComponent } from './b/b.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AComponent,
    BComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    AComponent,
    BComponent
  ]
})
export class SectionAModule { }
```

SectionB module (rather obvious)

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { BaComponent } from './ba/ba.component';
import { BbComponent } from './bb/bb.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    BaComponent,
    BbComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    BaComponent,
    BbComponent
  ]
})
export class SectionBModule { }
```

All-Sections Module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import {SectionAModule} from '../SectionA/SectionA.module';
import {SectionBModule} from '../SectionB/SectionB.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SectionAModule,
    SectionBModule
  ],
  exports: [
    SectionAModule,
    SectionBModule
  ]
})
export class AllSectionsModule { }
```

app.module only imports AllSectionsModule, then app.component.html looks like this:

```
<div>
  <app-a></app-a>
  <app-b></app-b>
  <app-ba></app-ba>
  <app-bb></app-bb>
</div>
```

Running the application works as expected:

[image]

But I can't find a way to reference 'bb' from 'a' like for example this for example:

[image]

in hopes of getting something like this when I just call 'a'.  This is 'a.html':

```
<p>
  a works!  and
  <app-b></app-b> from within Section A  component a WORKS

BUT:
  <app-bb></app-bb>
  This won't work no matter how I try to reference it.
</p>
```

Thanks in Advance !
Chuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can refer components from "Section A" to "Section B". While Declaring components in SectionB.module.ts.

Add the Components(to be shared) in your case it is "bbComponent" in **exports** Array as you have done in **declarations** arrays

e.g: exports: ['bbComponent'].

Now import **SectionB** module in SectionA.module.ts.

After that you will be able to use that component. That Won't be a good practice.

Instead make a shared module of components that you wish to use in different modules. That will avoid problem of circular reference problem.

Hope that Helped.

Comment: Yes, Danish.  You are correct.  I agree that isn't a good practice, but it IS a way to make it work.   I agree and thus I am accepting your answer though I hoped there was a better way.  Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want use component from another module you need export the component from module which contain the component and import this module to your module: you can find more info [here](https://angular.io/guide/sharing-ngmodules)